# What is the purpose of the flair on per-site metas?

Tags: support, flair, per-site-meta

Why do per-site metas offer flair?  By this, I mean, are users really keen on knowledge **about** the Q&A site about something?

Comment: +1, will make more sense to have the Meta profile offer the flair of the main site.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression it exists here for meta.so because it is just as easy to do it as for any other site. It's there, so why not have it enabled?

For other metas, you just have the rep of the main site

[edited because I had things the wrong way round - so wrong :-)]

Answer (score 0):

It's a good measure of activity on Meta. Someone with a couple silvers and a handfun of bronze badges has actually been using Meta. It's impossible to tell that from rep.